# How to install ubuntu-server non-interactively?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, containers

I'm trying to build a ubuntu-server container for a development environment, but I'm prompted to select a keyboard layout, and character set.

---

#### Running a container:

```
docker run --rm it ubuntu
```

In the container:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y ubuntu-server
```

(I'm then eventually prompted to select and keyboard, then charset.)

Container works - but it's interactive :( I want to repeat the process non-interactively with a Dockerfile.

---

#### A Dockerfile (which fails):

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ubuntu-server
```

Build it:

```
docker build -t ubuntu-server .
```

-- Failure

**How to build/install ubuntu-server non-interactively in a container?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to your Dockerfile before RUN command, this sets noninteractive mode for apt-get:

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
```

Comment: currently investigating the container functionality - it did build! thanks

Comment: This is not good practice because the environment variable will persist to past the build process, resulting in unexpected issues later on, especially if users can get a shell in the container, or you use docker exec. See this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/980134/668858